# which option is better, when there are way to many records?

Tags: java, sql, performance

Please suggest me which option is the best.

I have a table Student(id,name, create_date). It has way too many records(assume millions).
I have another table named student_stats(month, year, student_count) which is empty now. I will look over my student table and fill student_stats table.

student_stats will have data like this

```
month year  count
jan   2000    5
feb   2000    4
...
jan   2015    20
```

option 1:

```
List<MonthYearCount> monthYearCounts = select month(create_date), year(create_date), count(*) from Student where create_date between '2000-01-01' and '2015-02-01' group by month, year;

for(singleMonthYear : all month between '2000-01-01' and '2015-02-01'){
 MonthYearCount monthYearCount = monthYearCounts.get(singleMonthYear);
 studentStats = new StudentStats();
 studentStats.setMonth(monthYearCount.getMonth())
 studentStats.setYear(monthYearCount.getYear());
 studentStats.setCount(monthYearCount.getCount());
 studentStats.insertToDB();
}

class MonthYearCount{
int month;
int year;
int count;
}
```

option 2:

```
List<Student> students = select * from Student where create_date between '2000-01-01' and '2015-02-01;

for(singleMonthYear : all month between '2000-01-01' and '2015-02-01'){
  List<Student> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
  for(student : students){
     if(student.getCreateDate() is between singleMonthYear i.e. 2012-05-01 to 2012-05-31){
         filtered.add(student);
     }
  }


  studentStats = new StudentStats();
  studentStats.setMonth(singleMonthYear.getMonth())
  studentStats.setYear(singleMonthYear.getYear());
  studentStats.setCount(filtered.size());
  studentStats.insertToDB();
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `option 3` create field single date type column in your database

Comment: BTW Millions of records can be imported into memory but if the data starts in a database and ends up in a database, you may be better off performing the transformation entirely in the database.

Comment: I have to do it via java, actual scenario is complex.

Comment: @user902383 what field? can you elaborate?

Comment: If memory is an issue, you just need a process to read in a record and process it before reading in the next record (and remove all references to that record).  The data should be off on the TCP buffer before you read it in.  If you allow GC to do its job, you should be able to read in any number of records.